# Substitute for the lack of identity API?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I have a chrome extension which I would like to convert into an Edge extension. I attempted to use the conversion tool provided by Microsoft [(here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions) but it doesn't work, at all. I load the extension and the program just hangs, without updating the UI at all. It's a fairly complex extension, so I could understand why.

I've started to look into doing this myself, however I saw that the Identity API is not supported at all within Edge Extensions [(see here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis) which hinders my progress slightly, as I use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow to interact with our own Identity Provider.

Is there a way around this at all? Or any possible alternatives? We need to be able to authenticate against our own Identity Provider (which is running IdentityServer 3.)

Answer (score -1):

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483650/how-do-you-determine-identity-in-a-microsoft-edge-extension), as we know, [Edge does not support identity now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap). So we cannot get user identity using Edge extension APIs. Currently we do not have any tricky do get user identity and do not encourage to do it with a tricky method. The best and safety way is sign-in with your extension now.

Someone has create [a feedback to asks Edge support Identity API](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/17882014-support-chrome-identity-api), you could also add a vote.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've added a vote to the UserVoice issue you linked.

What do you mean by 'sign-in with your extension now'?